# Javascript findevenlengthstring and push() to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm just looking for some help. I feel like i'm over complicating the answer to a question but I'd love some help with it.

Question:

This function will take an array of values, and should return an array of all the even length strings.

Anything that's not a string, or not a string of even length, should not be returned in the array.

If there are no even length strings, it should return an empty array.

Answer so far:

```
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {
  let result = []; //array i want to push too
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){ //cycle through items array
  if(items[i] == typeof string){ //if the value is a string
    if(items[i] == 0 && items[i].length % 2 == 0) { //if the item is even
      result.push(items[i]); //push to array
    }
  } return result; //return the array
} return []; //else return empty array
}
```

Comment: What `items[i] == 0` is supposed to do?

Comment: You can simple do this with one-liner as `items.filter((x) => typeof x === 'string' && x.length % 2 === 0);`